# What does "DPs" mean?

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

After collaborating in writing a paper with a person, he submitted the paper to a journal, in his email to us, he wrote:

> It has been a nice collaboration, thanks for the excellent work!
>
> Should we make **DPs**? What I can offer is GLO, CEPR and UNU-MERIT, where
> I have affiliations.

I am wondering what does "**DPs**" stand for, I try to Google it but I did not find the meaning suitable to the context.

Comment: https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/DP -  *perhaps* "discussion paper," "data package," "development prototype," "distribution plan," "documentation plan," "development prototype, "decision paper"? I have no idea either. Perhaps the best thing would be to respond to him and ask for clarification because you are not sure what he means.

Comment: Might also be "discussion points".

Comment: Dumplings? What is the context?

Comment: The context has been updated

Comment: This would appear to be specific to your feild: _DPs_ means nothing to this native English speaker.

Comment: @ColinFine, I deem that it would not be a specific word in my area (even my background is Finance), it should be communicating word, I deem.

Comment: @Louise, I have no idea what you are trying to say in your reply to me. _Deem_ is an unusual word to use in this context, and tends to mean something like _choose to believe_ or _choose to consider_. I cannot make sense of it.

Comment: @ColinFine, sorry for confusing you, my bad. I mean, I do not think *DPs* is a specific word in my area, it should be a communicating word in this context.

Comment: @Louise You should ask your email partner what he means. This is not a well known or standard English abbreviation.

Comment: @Katy. Yes, I think it would be the case, I asked because English is my second language so I thought it is a widely used word in English communication.